# Failed to Open Display error while running python subprocess and Libreoffice 6.2 in CentOS6

Tags: python-3.x, linux, subprocess, centos6, libreoffice

I need to run **Libreoffice** `--covert-to` to convert an excel file to html page.
The current code works well within the windows machine. But in AWS, CentOS6, it's producing an error as **"Failed to open display"**.
Here is my code

```
import subprocess
cwdir = '/opt/libreoffice6.2/program'
excel_path = '/home/ec2-user/PythonCode/testing/Book1.xlsx'
dest_path = '/home/ec2-user/PythonCode/testing'
html_command = ["soffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "html", "--outdir", 
               dest_path, excel_path]
subprocess.run(html_command, shell=True, cwd=cwdir)`
```

Comment: The issue appears to be with LibreOffice. Are you certain you are using `soffice` from `/opt/libreoffice6.2/program`? Is it on-path? Maybe you should try `html_command = ["/opt/libreoffice6.2/programsoffice/soffice" ...]`. Also see [Bug 71064 - "Failed to open display" error in the help message when using LO via SSH](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71064) and [Bug 121275 - LibreOffice does not start on wayland without an Xwayland DISPLAY running](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121275). You should probably file a bug report.

Comment: I changed the code to  `html_command = ["/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/soffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "html", "--outdir", dest_path, excel_path]`still getting the same error, with one more message as **/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/soffice.bin: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /opt/libreoffice6.2/program/libmergedlo.so)** and **
/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/soffice.bin: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /opt/libreoffice6.2/program/libmergedlo.so)**

Comment: It would be better if you have commented the reason for your down vote so that I can improve it next time

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert excel file to html file with some minor changes. The values inside list is not working so I have to provide the `soffice convert-to` query as a string value and the folder contains the input excel file and destination folder , where the html file to be stored,must be different.

```
import subprocess
cwdir = '/opt/libreoffice6.2/program'
excel_path = '/home/ec2-user/PythonCode/testing/Book1.xlsx'
dest_path = '/home/ec2-user/PythonCode/testing/output'
html_command = r"soffice --headless --convert-to html --outdir " + " " + dest_path + " " + excel_path
subprocess.run(html_command, shell=True, cwd=cwdir)
```